# Why wasn't the quotient rule used for this particular question involving L'Hopital's Rule?

Tags: calculus

For this question, I used the quotient rule as such :

(f'*g-g'*f)/g^2

The only problem is that the answer to this question, they don't use the quotient rule, why ? [image: Here is the image of the problem]

Thanks,

Comment: 1. Please don't use images to convey information not otherwise present in your post. [Here is an explanation why](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34123/742) 2. Subject line should be about the mathematical content of your question, not about how you feel about the question ("challenging problem" doesn't belong there; it's really an expression of how you personally find the problem).

Comment: Re-read L'Hopital's Rule. Does it say that you find the limit of $f/g$ by looking at the limit of $(f/g)'$, or does it say something else?

Comment: $f'/g' \neq (f/g)'$

Comment: So only with l'hospital's rule do I not use quotient rule ? Further explanation would be appreciated. Thanks,

Comment: Read LHopital's Rule. It doesn't say "take the derivative of the quotient", it says something **entirely different**. Asking why is it that "only with LHopital do I not use quotient rule" is like asking why you don't use the quotient rule to find the derivative of a sum... It's because you aren't taking the derivative of a quotient.

Comment: Also, I can't use the product rule in l'hospital's rule ?

Comment: **Again:** The product rule and the quotient rule are tools used to *calculate derivatives*. L'Hopital's rule is a tool to calculate **limits**. They are different things to solve different problems. You also can't use determinants in L'Hopital's Rule, nor can you use cross-multiplication, nor can you use percentages, nor can you use set theory.

Answer (score 0):

The quotient rule, $\left( \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} \right)' = \frac{f'(x)g(x) - f(x)g'(x)}{(g(x))^2}$, is used to find the *derivative* of a quotient of two functions.  But this question did not ask you to find the derivative of $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$, but rather to find the *limit* of $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ as $x$ approaches 3 from the right -- an entirely different question.

Comment: Also, I can't use the product rule in l'hospital's rule ?

Answer (score 0):

L'Hopital's rule states that
when $f(x)\rightarrow 0$ and $g(x)\rightarrow 0$ when $x\rightarrow a$, we have that
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow a}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \lim_{x\rightarrow a}\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}
$$
We don't use the quotient rule because we are not calculating the derivative of a quotient of functions. L'Hopital's rule is telling us to derive the numerator and the denominator separately

Comment: Thank you ! I get it now !

Comment: Also, I can't use the product rule in l'hospital's rule ?

Comment: What do you mean by that? If computing the derivative of either the numerator or denominator requires you to take the derivative of a product of two functions, you use the product rule to compute the derivative of said numerator/denominator